# How can I select all items that don't have the matching ID?

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to select all the non-matching elements based on the fact that it matches or not the ID.

The user hover over the title in order to show or hide specific divs below.

```js
let menus = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-project");

Array.from(menus).forEach(function(menu) {
    menu.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.title);
   const visible = document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.title)
   const invisible = document.getElementById(":not(#" + e.target.dataset.title + ")")
//    visible.classList.add("visible");
//    invisible.classList.add("invisible");
   console.log(visible)
   console.log(invisible)

    });
});
```

```css
.visible {
display: block;
}

.visible {
display: invisible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-project">

  <div data-title="1" >I will show One and hide Two</div>
  <div data-title="2" >I will show Two and hide One</div>
</nav>

  <div id="1" class=""> One </div>
  <div id="2" class=""> Two </div>
```

Comment: Why not select the ID? There can only be one.

Comment: So you want to make the elements with matching id and title visible and the other invisible?

Comment: Please add some representative HTML in a snippet demo using the editor.

Comment: Also, `querySelectorAll()` eliminates the need for `Array.from()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-project").forEach(menu => {
    menu.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(child => {
        if (child.hasAttribute("data-title")){
            child.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
                menu.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(el => {
                    if (!el.hasAttribute("data-title") && el.id !== child.dataset.title){
                        el.classList.remove("visible");
                        el.classList.add("invisible");
                    };
                });
            });
            child.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                menu.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(el => {
                    el.classList.remove("invisible");
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.visible {
display: block;
}

.invisible {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<main class="nav-project cas">

  <div data-title="1" class="">I will show One and hide Two</div>
  <div data-title="2" class="">I will show Two and hide One</div>
  
  <div id="1" class=""> One </div>
  <div id="2" class=""> Two </div>

</main>
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm not sure this is working...

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you're trying to do. Please add some HTML and the expected behavior.

Comment: So you want to make the element we're hovering over visible and the others invisible inside the menu.nav-project?

Comment: I edited the post so you might find insight ! :) Thanks a lot

Comment: yep, thanks, seems to be working :) (you changed the html structure a bit, but I guess I'll figure it out haha)